# Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function (its in an async function though....)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have no clue what's causing this issue and I've spent at least 30 minutes searching google and trying different things with no solution. I've defined an `async` function and I'm trying to use `await` inside of it but its giving me the

> **Error:** Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Here is the code:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function SolveRecaptchaV2(APIKey, googleKey, pageUrl, proxy, proxyType){
            var requestUrl = "https://2captcha.com/in.php?key=" + APIKey + "&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey=" + googleKey + "&pageurl=" + pageUrl + "&proxy=" + proxy + "&proxytype=";

            switch (proxyType) {
                case 'HTTP':
                requestUrl = requestUrl + "HTTP";
                break;

                case 'HTTPS':
                requestUrl = requestUrl + "HTTPS";
                break;

                case 'SOCKS4':
                requestUrl = requestUrl + "SOCKS4";
                break;

                case 'SOCKS5':
                requestUrl = requestUrl + "SOCKS5";
                break;
            }   
            $.ajax({url: requestUrl, success: function(result){
                if(result.length < 3){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    if(result.substring(0, 3) == "OK|"){
                        var captchaID = result.substring(3);

                        for(var i=0; i<24; i++){
                            var ansUrl = "https://2captcha.com/res.php?key=" + APIKey + "&action=get&id=" + captchaID;  

                            $.ajax({url: ansUrl, success: function(ansresult){
                                    console.log(ansresult);
                                    if(ansresult.length < 3){
                                        return ansresult;
                                    }else{
                                        if(ansresult.substring(0, 3) == "OK|"){
                                            return ansresult;
                                        }else if (ansresult != "CAPCHA_NOT_READY"){
                                            return ansresult;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            await sleep(1000);
                        }

                    }else{
                        return ansresult;   
                    }
                }
            },
            fail: function(){
                return "";
                }
            });

        }
```

EDIT::  Now, when i make the $.ajax callback function an async function, neither of the $.ajax calls work, and any console.log's i make inside of them dont show in the console... i dont get any errors though

Comment: Are you sure? In this code, `function(result){` isn't `async`.

Comment: `await` is being used in your callback function, which is not declared `async`.

Comment: You're not using it inside your `async` function, you're using it *several functions deeper*, inside your `$.ajax` callback.

Comment: You might consider the `fetch` API, which uses promises instead of callbacks.

Comment: @JoshLee With the solution to this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Comment: wow haha i cant believe i didnt notice that

Comment: Don't use `success` callbacks! `$.ajax` returns a promise which you can (and should!) `await`.

Comment: Now, when i make the $.ajax callback function an async function, neither of the $.ajax calls work, and any console.log's i make inside of them dont show in the console... i dont get any errors though

Answer (score 1):

So the main issue here is, you're using await within the success function from `$.ajax` function (This is not possible, without making this function async as well, but now because your code is mixing callbacks/async, you're not able to resolve the original Promise of `SolveRecaptchaV2`. You're mixing async with old callbacks.) Your code is essentially doing:

```
SolveRecaptchaV2 => Ajax Request => Ajax Request Done, Firing callback
                         V                         V
                     Returning         Returning (But nothing cares about this return)
```

If you're using async functions, try to utilize async as much as possible. `$.ajax` will return a promise, so we can await that, and keep our function completely async:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function SolveRecaptchaV2(APIKey, googleKey, pageUrl, proxy, proxyType){
    var requestUrl = "https://2captcha.com/in.php?key=" + APIKey + "&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey=" + googleKey + "&pageurl=" + pageUrl + "&proxy=" + proxy + "&proxytype=";

    switch (proxyType) {
        case 'HTTP':
        requestUrl = requestUrl + "HTTP";
        break;

        case 'HTTPS':
        requestUrl = requestUrl + "HTTPS";
        break;

        case 'SOCKS4':
        requestUrl = requestUrl + "SOCKS4";
        break;

        case 'SOCKS5':
        requestUrl = requestUrl + "SOCKS5";
        break;
    }   
    try {
        await result = await $.ajax({url: requestUrl});

        if(result.length < 3) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if(result.substring(0, 3) == "OK|") {
                var captchaID = result.substring(3);

                for(var i=0; i<24; i++){
                    var ansUrl = "https://2captcha.com/res.php?key=" + APIKey + "&action=get&id=" + captchaID;  

                    var ansResult = await $.ajax({url: ansUrl});
                    console.log(ansResult);
                    if(ansResult.length < 3) {
                        return ansResult;
                    } else {
                        if(ansresult.substring(0, 3) == "OK|") {
                            return ansResult;
                        } else if (ansResult != "CAPCHA_NOT_READY") {
                            return ansResult;
                        }
                    }
                    await sleep(1000);
                }
            } else {
                // ansResult is not defined here, not sure what you want to return here (May want to return false, or an empty string):
                return ansResult;   
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        //On ajax failure, return empy string. (May want to return false here, to fall inline with your "if (result.length < 3)" statement above.)
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now our chain looks like this:

```
SolveRecaptchaV2 => Ajax Request
                     => Ajax Request Done
                       => Get Answer URL
                         => Sleep
                           => Get Answer URL
                             => Sleep (...loop)
                               => Resolve promise of SolveRecaptchaV2.
```